# Change Casing in WCF Service Reference

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I'm creating a service reference to a web service written in Java.  The generated classes now follow the Java casing convention used in the web service, for example class names are camelCase rather than PascalCase.

Is there a way to get the desired casing from the service reference?

CLARIFICATION:

With WSE based services, one could modify the generated Reference.cs to provide .NET standard casing and use XmlElementAttribute to map to the Java naming presented by the external web service, like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("resultType", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
public virtual MyResultType ResultType
{ ... }
```

Not terribly maintenance-friendly without writing custom code to either generate the proxy code or modify it after it's been generated.

What I'm after is one or more options to present a WCF generated client proxy to calling applications using the .NET casing conventions, achieving the same as I did previously with WSE.  Hopefully with less manual effort.

Comment: Huh? If you make a service reference, it has the casing of the service. Always.

Comment: Clarified that I'm looking for the easiest path to present .NET casing to other parts of the application and provided an example of how I previously accomplished that with WSE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your WCF client proxies are *partial classes*, you could always add a second file for the same class, which implements the `PascalCasedMethodName` for each `javaCasedMethodName` and then just call the Java method from your new method.

```
public partial class MyClientProxy
{ 
   ......
   public MyResultType GetResultType(string inputParam)
   { 
       return this.getResultType(inputParam);
   }
   ......
}
```

Seems a bit redundant - but that should really work, I think. Since your code is stored in a separate file, it won't be overwritten if you re-create the client proxy - and since it's the second part of a partial class, it will be "merged into" the class definition for your client code to call.

Comment: The problem is that it's not just the method names but also the types that are incorrectly (for .NET) cased.  There's a fairly deep class hierarchy involved in the input and output, so copying between the generated classes and duplicate-with-correct-casing classes would be problematic.